# Software for Bayesian Linear Regression

Tags: bayesian

What kind of software is there for Bayesian Linear Regression? 
I'm trying to learn by myself, and would like something user-friendly if possible.

I've searched but there's too many options, and I have no idea which one I should choose.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: One to look at: the R `MCMCpack` package.

Comment: What Bayesian aspects are you looking for? Any standard linear regression analysis is a Bayesian linear regression analysis using the standard default prior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a dynamically developing field, so multiple software packages are available and are being developed.

You can check [arm](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/arm/index.html) package that accompanies [*Data Analysis Using Regression and Multilevel/Hierarchical Models*](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/arm/) book by Andrew Gelman and Jennifer Hill, it has `bayesglm` function for calculating GLM models using EM algorithm.

Recently, [two new packages](http://thinkinator.com/2016/01/12/r-users-will-now-inevitably-become-bayesians/) for regression models in R were published: [brms](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/brms/index.html) and [rstanarm](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rstanarm/index.html). Both of the packages just provide R interface and use Stan as workhorse. There is also recent [rethinking](https://github.com/rmcelreath/rethinking) package that accompanies *Statistical Rethinking* book by Richard McElreath.

Generally, if you are looking for R packages for Bayesian estimation check [CRAN "Bayesian" task view](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Bayesian.html).

Those packages are good for start, but it is good idea to look at software dedicated to Bayesian estimation: [Stan](http://mc-stan.org/) and [JAGS](http://mcmc-jags.sourceforge.net/). You would need to put a little bit more effort into learning them, but they are much more flexible than the out-of-the-box solutions. Moreover, Stan has [over 500 pages long detailed user manual](http://mc-stan.org/documentation/) that provides very good introduction to both Bayesian methods and the software itself. When learning JAGS you can check [*The BUGS Book*](http://www.mrc-bsu.cam.ac.uk/software/bugs/the-bugs-project-the-bugs-book/) by David Lunn, Christopher Jackson, Nicky Best, Andrew Thomas and David Spiegelhalter that is a very nice introduction to Bayesian modelling and the software.

Comment: @Scortchi it depends... ;) If you need to learn R to use those libraries that it won't be much harder than learning Stan or JAGS. For people who are fluent in R using the libraries would be pretty obvious, but learning JAGS or Stan should also not be a problem. IMHO, Stan and JAGS are really very intuitive so it is not that hard to learn them.

Answer (score 1):

The book *Doing Bayesian Data Analysis: A Tutorial with R, JAGS, and Stan* is a really gentle introduction to using the common tools for Bayesian regressions. Also, [his blog has solution codes for all of the exercises](https://sites.google.com/site/doingbayesiandataanalysis/exercises). You can do most common things just by modifying the example solutions. I highly recommend this as an introductory resource.

I don't know of any "point-and-click" tools so I think no matter what you do, you have to get comfortable programming in at least one language.